# PHP rankings and more

Tags: php, ranking

Guys I need help with some php queries on my scores database.

I have had this question answered very well before and it worked wonderfully until I lost my computer with the solution on it and i didn't post the working code to refer to in the question...which, well, sucks for me I suppose.

Anyone who answers this to the extent whereby I get the results I need will be immediately paid $50 via any receipt means they wish (if they wish to accept the offer that is, as I'm unsure of the rules here and don't want to break them).

I have an outside application that posts two variables to a php script that is intended do the following:

To find the highest place the user ranks in the table echoing the rank, name and score in a specific format (as per the code).

first variable is: $limit which defines the number of results required. (posted from the application)

second variable is $name which is the username I am looking for. (posted from the application)

(I have tested and the application does post the name and the php will echo it every time when testing)

This is what I have so far but it only shows the name of the desired user along with the rank and score of the top player (not the user in this instance).

```
<?php
include("common.php");
$link=dbConnect();

$limit = safe($_POST['limit']);
$name = safe($_POST['name']);


$query = "SELECT name, score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM $dbName . `scores`, (
SELECT @curRank := 0
) q
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT $limit";

$result = mysql_query($query);    
$my_err = mysql_error();

if($result === false || $my_err != '')
 {
 echo "";
 }

$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

 if ( $row['name'] = $name ) 
 {
    // output this row because it's for the specified user
    echo $row[rank] . " ". $row['name'] . " - " . $row['score'] . "\n";
 } 

 else 

 {
    continue;
 }
 }
 ?>
```

really need some help here.

Comment: you are using an obsolete extension `mysql_` and you have a typo : `$row[rank]` - should be `$row['rank']`

Comment: Thanks for your observations! Help, however, is still required.